# Is there a modern English translation of the Bible that uses the second-person plural pronoun?

Tags: greek, hebrew

I'm looking for a modern translation of the Bible (ideally in the public domain) that retains the distinction between second-person plural and second-person singular.  In Early Modern English (the language of the King James Bible) when speaking to a single person, ["thou", "thee", "thy", and "thine"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou) were used.  When talking to a crowd, "ye", "you", "your", and "yours" were correct.  These days the plural form and "ye" are universally replaced with the "you" forms.  Since both Greek and Hebrew make this distinction, it's useful to know which form the original language used.  (A rule of thumb is that the plural is nearly always used in the New Testament letters.)  We lost something when English simplified to "you".

I know that the [ASV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Version) was pretty strict about using the right number for second-person pronouns.  But it was published before the discovery of the Dead Sea scrolls and uses lots of other archaic language, so I'd like to find something newer.  Many of the more modern versions either do not use the archaic forms or only use them for addressing God.  So they aren't useful for my purpose.

Is there any modern English translation that *does* distinguish between singular and plural second-person pronouns?

---

### Why I ask

My pastor has been been talking about the importance of community in the Bible and a few weeks ago he pointed out this deficiency in Modern English.  He's from Florida (via Kentucky) and pointed out that [Southern American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) has a solution to this problem: "y'all".  As a semi-serious joke, I'd like to produce a version of the Bible that I will call the Southern American Version™ or SAV for short. It turns out that I can mechanically produce this from the ASV.  Here's 1<sup>st</sup> Peter 2:9-10 (SAV) as an example:

> 9 But **y'all** are a elect race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a
>   people for God's own possession, that **y'all** may show forth the excellencies of
>   him who called **y'all** out of darkness into his marvellous light: 10 who in time
>   past were no people, but now are the people of God: who had not obtained
>   mercy, but now have obtained mercy.

That comes out ok, but other passages just sound outdated and strange.  2<sup>nd</sup> Corinthians 3:1-3 (SAV):

> 1 Are we beginning again to commend ourselves? or need we, as do some, epistles of commendation to **y'all** or from **y'all**? 2 **Y'all** are our epistle, written in our hearts, known and read of all men; 3 being made manifest that **y'all** are an epistle of Christ, ministered by us, written not with ink, but with the Spirit of the living God; not in tables of stone, but in tables *that are* hearts of flesh.

Y'all got any suggestions?

Comment: Working on this project has taught be more [English grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57613/10754) than I imaged I'd ever need to know after leaving elementary school.

Comment: This sounds kinda like the [Cotton Patch Gospel](http://rockhay.tripod.com/cottonpatch/).

Comment: *NWT* uses small block caps to indicate plurality. Not perfect, but it does the job. Here in the Irish midlands, *ye* would be the preferred plural form. In Dublin, Northern Ireland, and parts of Scotland, *youse* is normal. In parts of Northern England, singular *thou* is still used.

Comment: My father, who is a linguist, claims that the theologians overwork the importance of the number of the second person pronoun. The community/individual dialectic is certainly a critical one in Scripture, but it is easy to go to far in studying it in the details of the pronouns.

Comment: Have you not received a valid answer? Please mark the acceptable answer(s).

Answer (score 8):

I would take a look at the NRSV. Depending on which version you get (there is a Catholic NRSV as well) you will commonly find a "you all" or "all of you" instead of simply "you." Although rather than being a "word-for-word" or "thought-for-thought" translation, it is somewhere in between. It does a fairly good job of making grammatical distinctions where important and providing the theological or historical idea where that is more important.

Also... the NKJV does a lot of what you might be looking for as well.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics—Stack Exchange!  Thanks for the answer, but I don't think either one does the second-person plural regularly, at least not for my test passages.  (See 2nd Corinthians 3:1-3: [NKJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%203:1-3&version=NKJV).  The [NRSV](http://bible.oremus.org/?ql=198740814) does better, with "you yourselves" but it's not enough in my opinion.)

Comment: You yourselves is actually because of the grammar in the Greek, not specifically because it is plural, but because of the construction, so I see what you're saying. Are you getting your comparisons for test passages directly from the KJV?

Comment: Nevermind... I see you used the ASV

Comment: I'm doing a naive conversion of "you" => "y'all" and "thou" => "you" from the ASV.  But then I have to figure out how to deal with a whole mess of outdated words like "begat" and "guideth".   It's a fun, goofy little project for me that, I hope, will end in a unique gift for my pastor.

Answer (score 5):

The lack of second person plural is one of the least significant differences between Hebrew and English. It almost never leads to confusion, since context resolves the referent in nearly all cases. The suggestion of using y'all is no good, as y'all has backwoods connotations in English that the plural you doesn't have in Hebrew (or Greek).

Douglas Hofstadter has considered this issue regarding translation from French, where the second person plural "vous" and the second person singular "tu" are similarly distinguished, and further have a formal/informal connotation. His solution was to use a capitalized you, "You", for the second person plural.

This solution works for Hebrew. In reading aloud, a tonal difference can indicate the initial capital. So "You" would be pronounced "YOU" with high-tone (stress), while "you" is pronounced in the normal tone.

While doing the [Wikisource translation](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_%28Wikisource%29), I will try to consistently use this convention for the Hebrew from this point on. I'll fix up the translated Hebrew to follow this convention also.

EDIT: The confusion brought up [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/is-there-a-modern-english-translation-of-the-bible-that-uses-the-second-person-p/1440#comment2447_1440) with the capitalization convention regarding God is giving me second thoughts about this--- people will get confused. I think it is somewhat better to italicize plural you, you<sup>f</sup>,*you*, *you*<sup>f</sup>, to give the four forms: singular/*plural* generic-masculine/feminine<sup>f</sup>. Further, the "f" subscript need only be used when there is confusion (as in the handful of feminine God references in the uncorrected Masoretic).

Comment: @GoneQuiet: Oh, good point! I did not consistently do the capitalization thing in regard to God, because there are some places where you aren't sure about whether the pronoun refers to God or not, and I wanted to preserve the ambiguity.

Comment: @GoneQuiet: One could use _you_ (italics) for God consistently, and this might be ok. I am wary of this because of the two or three places where the pronoun is not for sure God.

Comment: @GoneQuiet: It will bother you, I'll make up a passage: The Amorites have risen, and Israel's daughters are taken captive, their tears upon their hem. Their tears like water down a stream. Their eyes redden, and they call to God: God, awaken from _your_ slumber and release us from captivity. Our hopes have faded. And God answered them, saying "I have heard y'all, and I shall release yous's chains".

Comment: And you have to eliminate anachronistic punctuation if favor of inclusios, colophons, etc. And drop any meaning based on vowel points which were added circa 5-600 AD. There is a great value in retaining the original ambiguity.

Comment: @BobJones: That's ridiculous. The text was in continuous reading use, and people knew the pronounciation of everything. They just wrote it down. There is not a huge amount of vowel ambiguity anyway, a dozen words per book at most.

Comment: @RonMaimon. *I have heard ye, and I shall release your chains.* (*Your* is the original English plural. No need to go making one up. For clarity, use *thou* for the singular.)

Answer (score 5):

Different languages have different distinctions. The idea that something is "lost" is not entirely true. As another person commented, the purported "loss" is solved by context. All languages use redundancy, e.g. agreement, which makes sure that the message gets across.

Your pastor is right to note the importance of community in the Bible, and the lack of it in modern, North American culture, including the church. But that is a problem of such scope that it cannot possibly be solved, or even helped much, by a focus on pronouns, especially when there are explicit texts in the NT which address the issue very clearly and in which nothing is lost to the lack of a plural second person pronoun in English.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics!  Thanks for the reminder that we don't _always_ have to go back to the original language in order to understand Bible passage.  I wanted to note here that my question was motivated less by a desire to understand the Bible and more by the desire to have a little fun with my pastor.  It's also an interesting project to fool around with. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The New World Translation of The Holy Scriptures uses the capitalized YOU and YOUR convention to distinguish the second person plural. It's also, in my personal opinion, an excellent translation because it strives to convey the original thought accurately, rather than by paraphrase. It also disguishes between a number of tenses more accurately for example "Keep on, then, seeking first the kingdom" (NW) versus "But seek first the kingdom" (NIV) at Matthew 6:33.

The text is available online here: http://www.watchtower.org/e/bible/index.htm

And some background information is available here: http://www.watchtower.org/e/20080501a/article_01.htm

Comment: Welcome to _Biblical Hermeneutics.SE_!  Do you know what license governs making copies and changing the NWT?  A public domain translation has the advantage of being free from copyright restrictions.  Also, there are some [potential problems](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1161/68) with that translation's accuracy.  But otherwise, this is a helpful suggestion. (+1)

Comment: Jon, you point to John 1:1 "The word was God" (KJV). Granted, this is the traditional rendering of the verse but that does not mean it is the correct rendering. NW is not the only translation that renders John 1:1 that way. Please see: http://www.watchtower.org/e/ti/article_08.htm#john1 for other examples. The Watchtower Bible and Tract Society of Pennsylvania holds the copyright but they distribute hardcopies free of charge (the printing is supported by voluntary donations). Thanks for the +1!

Comment: I encourage you to take a shot at answering the question I linked to.  Comments aren't really the best place to sort through such questions.  (Also, I see the only answer is pretty one-sided and it would be great to have the opposite viewpoint represented.)

Comment: @JonEricson. For some reason, none of the Watchtower Society's stuff is available under free-content licenses.

Comment: @John. The publishers are the Watchtower Bible and Tract Society of New York, and copyright is held by the Watch Tower Bible and Tract Society of Pennsylvania. Note the difference between *Watchtower* and *Watch Tower*.

Comment: Correct, it is not public domain. As you mentioned the Society holds the copyright. I just figured I'd mention it because it happened to offer the feature he was looking for. Print copies are freely available, though, for individuals. They don't charge for any of their literature (the printing is supported by optional voluntary donations). I'm not sure what arrangements are possible for a bulk order. So perhaps it could be useful in hardcopy form.

Comment: @John  Ironically your example "Keep on, then, seeking first the kingdom" lacks the pronoun indicating the second person plural. The KJV has "seek ye". But yes, the NWT you/YOU feature, while visually odd does do the trick in a lot of situations.

Comment: The Achilles Heel of the NWT for my purposes is that it isn't incorporated into any other tools such as Logos.com, BibleGateway.com, BibleHub.com.  I wonder if it is reticence on the Watchtower Society or the policy of not allowing non-Trinitarians to "buy or sell" within their domain. Either way I hope the situation changes as it would increase discussion on this site dramatically!

Answer (score 4):

I've recently created a Google Chrome plugin that does this on a few bible websites: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/texan-bible-2nd-person-pl/hecahobcfkfdpifomfgoikegbeeiolmd

It's also an option here: http://biblewebapp.com/app/

Comment: Open up the options panel (gear) and click the Texas icon :) Note, it's just NT for now, but I'll get the OT in there in a few days.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome.  I'm giving you a big ol' +1 for your works which is _exactly what I was looking for_!  I'd love to accept and make a big deal your answer... but it's not really a full answer.  Maybe you could copy-n-paste the details text you wrote up for the app.  But even better would be if you explained how you managed it.  Did you learn something new about the Biblical languages?  I'd love to hear more.  In any case, a hearty "Welcome to [Hermeneutics.SE] to you!"

Comment: This is so funny- I remembered this from your blog, and was going to mention it. Major shout out here: If you haven't read Dyer's book "From the Garden to The City," you are missing out. This dude is one of the coolest people out the right now!