# Why is the Greek word Θεὸς in John 1:1c treated as a proper noun in English Translation?

Tags: greek, john, translation-philosophy

Why is the Greek word   Θεὸς in John 1:1c treated as a proper noun in English Translation?

John 1:1

New International Version
In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was **God.**

New Living Translation
In the beginning the Word already existed. The Word was with God, and the Word was **God**.

English Standard Version
In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was **God**.

New American Standard Bible 
In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was **God**

I am specifically asking why the Greek word Θεὸς in John 1:1c treated as a "proper noun"(if the Greek is qualitative in sense) in English Translation?

Comment: Please clarify if you meant something other than what was already asked and  answered in the other. Thanks.

Comment: @Susan, I am specifically asking why the Greek word Θεὸς in John 1:1c treated as a "proper noun" (if the Greek is qualitative in sense) in English Translation? The reason i asked is that i don't really know anything scholarly on this yet.

Comment: I think the top answer on the linked question argues that it is definite, though, and the definite θεός is always translated as proper in the NT as far as I know.

Comment: @Susan, In what sense it is 'definite'? Like the 'ton theon' in John 1:1b?

Comment: I think maybe you’re looking at [this](https://www.teknia.com/newtestamentgreek1/exegetical-insight-chapter-6-daniel-b-wallace), and it’s true that Wallace [has argued that it’s not definite](http://goo.gl/eiS1ed) (p. 268 there) - an argument he acknowledges is unusual, and one that disagrees with the top answer on the question I linked. I still think it’s essentially the same question, though.

Comment: (cont.) The difference between “a god” and “God” in English is both one of definiteness and of proper vs common, and it seems unnecessary to create another question just because that part of it hasn’t been addressed adequately in your view (and you may be right!).  [Another answer there](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2729) deals with Wallace’s argument more specifically, and [this one](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/7558) also demonstrates an appreciation for the “qualitative” nuance - either of those authors may be willing to expand to address your question if you comment.

Comment: @Susan, Thanks for your response.I have learned a lot.